# Using the AppDelegate as your Lowest Level WindowController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

When you first create an Application in XCode, at it's lowest level it creates the **AppDelegate.h/.m**  and a **MainWindow.xib**

Once you start modifying the Xib to best suit your design needs - is it best practice to move away from the AppDelegate as the initial Controller or is it always better to create a new WindowController to use with the MainWindow.xib ??

Fritzables

Answer (score 0):

The AppDelegate class cannot be used as a view controller, if that's what you're asking. Your AppDelegate class should be creating an instance of your main View Controller, which loads your main .xib file. Unless you're referring to defining the main Xib in your target configurations, but that's pretty old school.

Are you constrained by the version of iOS you need to support? Because you could avoid using .xib files altogether by using storyboards if you can use iOS 5.0 and up.

Comment: Hi Simon,  The StoryBoard I am pretty happy with so I have no issues with that at all.  I have the latest XCode 4.  I have always been a little confused when coding under OSX.  I have recently come across from a Win enviroment to Mac, still trying to get my head around how some things are done.

Answer (score 0):

Well good question. To me app delegate always has been a initial step to define a project that I create. There are many use for delegates but that is another subject. If you look at the apple doc's related to this subject (over view section) in the following link, there is a great explanation of what is the function of the app delegate there. To answer the question you ask, it is always a good practice to leave the app delegate and create a new controller and execute whatever function you want in there. Here is the link to apple do's and I hope it clears up everything for you my friend. Happy coding.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html